# How can I override a module's singleton method?

Tags: ruby

Given a module with a singleton method like this:

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      puts "method bar from Foo"
    end
  end
end
```

How can I override `Foo.bar` using another module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Extend and alias

My problem was that I forgot to think through the inheritance chain. I was
looking for a way to override the method by modifying the inheritance chain, but
that's not possible.

The reason is that `bar` is defined on `Foo` itself, so it never looks up its inheritance chain for the method. Therefore, to change `bar`, I have to change it on `Foo` itself.

While I **could** just re-open Foo, like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "new foo method"
  end
end
```

... I prefer a way to be able to wrap the original `bar` method, as though I
were subclassing and could call `super`. I can achieve that by setting up an
alias for the old method.

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      "method bar from Foo"
    end
  end
end

puts Foo.bar # => "method bar from Foo"

module FooEnhancement

  # Add a hook - whenever a class or module calls `extend FooEnhancement`,
  # run this code
  def self.extended(base)

    # In the context of the extending module or class 
    # (in this case, it will be Foo), do the following
    base.class_eval do

      # Define this new method
      def self.new_bar
        "#{old_bar} - now with more fiber!"
      end

      # Set up aliases. 
      # We're already in the context of the class, but there's no
      # `self.alias`, so we need to call `alias` inside this block
      class << self

        # We can call the original `bar` method with `old_bar`
        alias :old_bar :bar

        # If we call `bar`, now we'll get our `new_bar` method
        alias :bar :new_bar
      end
    end

  end

end

# This will fire off the self.extended hook in FooEnhancement
Foo.extend FooEnhancement

# Calls the enhanced version of `bar`
puts Foo.bar # => 'method bar from Foo - now with more fiber!'
```

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      puts "method bar from Foo"
    end
  end
end
```

is equal to

```
class << Foo
  def bar
    puts "method bar from Foo"
  end
end
```

that is also equal to

```
def Foo.bar
  puts "method bar from Foo"
end
```

So, you can call it to redefine this method everywhere where `Foo` is defined (ever withing another module, without including `Foo`).

Comment: Did not know `class << Foo`, nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
module Foo
    class << self
        def bar
            puts "method bar from Foo"
        end
        def baz
            puts "method baz from Foo"
        end
    end
end
module Foo2
    def Foo.bar
        puts "new version of bar"
    end
end
include Foo
Foo.baz #=> method baz from Foo
Foo.bar #=> new version of bar
```

Or instead of naming it `Foo2` simply re-open `Foo`.

```
module Foo
    class << self
        def bar
            puts "method bar from Foo"
        end
        def baz
            puts "method baz from Foo"
        end
    end
end
module Foo
    class << self
        def bar
            puts "new version of bar"
        end
    end
end
include Foo
Foo.baz #=> method baz from Foo
Foo.bar #=> new version of bar
```